# How to stop exercise mats from slipping on a hardwood floor in a multi-use room?

Tags: hardwood-floor

So I purchased some folding exercise mats to put in my basement.  The allocated floor space is multi-use, so I need to be able to put the mats away when not in use.

The problem I am running into is that the mats slide around rather easily on the smooth hardwood floor.  I'd like to find a way to keep them from sliding around, but with the following considerations:

1. I don't want to damage the hardwood floor, of course.
2. I don't want to install anchors in the floor.  Some type of anchoring
   on the baseboard trim around the perimeter *might* be ok.
3. I need to be able to setup the mats and tear them back down quickly. 
   Currently, I can just fold them up and put them away in less than
   one minute (it's only two mats).  I'd like to keep around that
   timeframe - i.e. no super complicated setups.
4. I don't want to get the floor "sticky" with some adhesive or anti-slip coating.

I'm fine with putting something on the underside of the mats, so long as it doesn't leave a residue on the floor.

I'd prefer not to be forced to place heavy weights on the mats to keep them in place, because a)  it takes up space on the mats (I only have about 64 sq ft), and b) I'd be nervous about dropping the weights and causing personal injury or damage to the floor.

Can anyone recommend a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into non-slip rug pads. They work well for me on our laminate floor and come in various sizes.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for the words for.  They are for rugs and work great.

Answer (score 0):

You could try spraying the bottom of the mats with *automotive undercoat*. It is a rubberized spray coating that should grip nicely on a smooth floor. You probably would not have to coat the entire underside, maybe just a few spots. It's pretty inexpensive too:

[image]